# Replace getContextLoader deprecated Spring 3 to 4

Tags: java, spring

I had this code which works with Spring 3 :

```
public class WebConsoleStarter extends ContextLoaderListener {
    
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebConsoleStarter.class);

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ...
        super.contextInitialized(event);
      initializeWebClient(event.getServletContext() ,  getContextClassLoader().getCurrentWebApplicationContext());
      ...
    }

    private void initializeWebClient(ServletContext servletContext, WebApplicationContext context) {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)context.getBean("connectionFactory");
        servletContext.setAttribute(WebClient.CONNECTION_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, connectionFactory);
        WebClient.initContext(servletContext);
    }


}
```

But this code can't work with Spring4 because the getContextLoader does not exist anymore.
I see there is a "getContextClassLoader" method, but seems to be different.

I see in spring documentation this phrase :

"org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.getContextLoader()
in favor of simply subclassing ContextLoaderListener itself (which extends ContextLoader, as of Spring 3.0)"

But don't understand what I have to do really here in my code :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replace the old by :

```
public class WebConsoleStarter extends ContextLoaderListener {
    
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebConsoleStarter.class);

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ...
        super.contextInitialized(event);
      initializeWebClient(event.getServletContext() ,  ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext());
      ...
    }

    private void initializeWebClient(ServletContext servletContext, WebApplicationContext context) {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)context.getBean("connectionFactory");
        servletContext.setAttribute(WebClient.CONNECTION_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, connectionFactory);
        WebClient.initContext(servletContext);
    }


}
```